# MultiByteToWideChar wchar * to char *

Tags: c

Here is func :

```
char *ToLowerSTR(/*char*/ WCHAR* buffer) // NEED TO FIX UNRESOLVED EXTERNAL
{
    CHAR* str;
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, str, strlen(str) + 1, buffer, sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(WCHAR));
....
return str;
}
```

and error :

> LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "char * __cdecl ToLowerSTR(char *)"
>   (?ToLowerSTR@@YAPADPAD@Z) referenced
>   in function "unsigned long __cdecl
>   GetPID(char *)"  )

how can I conver wchar * to char * ?

Comment: BTW, I don't see anything peculiar to C++0x (or even c++) here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your linker is trying to find a function like:

```
char * ToLowerSTR(char *)
```

but you have defined your function to take `WCHAR` as argument.
Look at the declaration of your function and see if it says `WCHAR*` or `char*`

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to your header file declaring a `char * ToLowerSTR(char *)` whereas your cpp file has a different function, `char * ToLowerSTR(WCHAR *)`

In order to correctly convert, you need to pass the length of the WCHAR buffer to your `ToLowerStr` function (Why ToLower btw, what is it supposed to do?). You cannot use `sizeof` on the passed `WCHAR *` - that'll give you the size of a pointer, not the length of the buffer it points to.

```
bool charToWChar(char const * Source, wchar_t * Dest, size_t DestLen) {
  return MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, Source, -1, Dest, DestLen) != 0;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
char const * myString = "abc";
wchar_t Buffer[100];
charToWChar(myString, Buffer, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

What Default said, plus: OMG, you're putting stuff into where `str` points, without pointing it in the right direction (like `new` or `malloc`) first..!